# Concatenate variables in single quote in php

Tags: php, html

I want to concatenate variables in single quotes in PHP with the following code.

```
onclick="copy('.$color->colorcode_2.', this)"
```

What I am trying to get result after execution.

```
onclick="copy('#ffffff', this)"
```

But getting this

```
onclick="copy(#ffffff, this)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's in PHP code, you need to escape single quotes.

```
onclick="copy(\'' . $color->colorcode_2 . '\', this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template strings like this:

```
onclick="'copy('{$color->colorcode_2}', this)'";
```